# Linq2db QueryExpressionMethod is throwing value cannot be null, but works with Association keys

Tags: c#, linq, linq2db

I'm trying to convert the Linq2db Association based on keys, to Association method (to clean up other parts of code):

This code works:

```
    [Association( CanBeNull = true, ThisKey = nameof( AccountId ), OtherKey = nameof( Common.Account.AccountId ) )]
    public List<AccountPayment> AccountPayments { get; set; }
```

This code doesn't work:

```
    [Association( CanBeNull = true, QueryExpressionMethod = nameof (LatestPaymentImpl)]
    public List<AccountPayment> AccountPayments { get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<Account, IDataContext, IQueryable<Repositories.Models.Common.AccountPayment>>> LatestPaymentImpl()
    {
        return ( ap, db ) => db.GetTable<AccountPayment>().Where( acc => acc.AccountId == ap.AccountId );
```

The exception I get is:

> "reason": "ArgumentException",
> "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: arg0",
> "status": "badRequest",
> "stackTrace": "   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance,
> MethodInfo method, Expression arg0, Expression arg1, Expression
> arg2)\r\n   at
> LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.TableBuilder.AssociatedTableContext.GetAssociationQueryExpression(Expression
> dataContextExpr, Expression parentObjExpression, Type parentType,
> Expression parentTableExpression, LambdaExpression queryMethod)\r\n
> at
> LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.TableBuilder.AssociatedTableContext..ctor(ExpressionBuilder
> builder, TableContext parent, AssociationDescriptor association)\r\n
> at
> LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.TableBuilder.TableContext.b__71_6(AssociationDescriptor
> a)\r\n   at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n  at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
> source)\r\n   at
> LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.TableBuilder.TableContext.GetAssociation(Expression
> expression, Int32 level)\r\n   at
> LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.TableBuilder.TableContext.GetAssociation(Expression
> expression, Int32 level)

Both are fairly simple cases, so I'm not sure how to investigate this further.

Linq2db version is 2.7.0.

Involved classes:

```
[Table( Name = "Account", Schema = "Common" )]
public class Account : ISoftDeletableRepositoryModel
{
    #region Members

    [Column( "AccountId" ), Identity, PrimaryKey]
    public Guid AccountId { get; set; }

    [Column( "Deleted", SkipOnUpdate = true ), NotNull]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    [Column( "Name" ), NotNull]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Association( CanBeNull = true, ThisKey = nameof( AccountId ), OtherKey = nameof( Security.UserAccount.AccountId ) )]
    public UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }

    [Association( CanBeNull = true, ThisKey = nameof( AccountId ), OtherKey = nameof( Common.Account.AccountId ) )]
    public List<AccountPayment> LatestAccountPayment { get; set; }
}

[Table( Name = "AccountPayment", Schema = "Common" )]
public class AccountPayment : ISoftDeletableRepositoryModel
{
    #region Members

    [Column( "AccountPaymentId" ), Identity, PrimaryKey]
    public Guid AccountPaymentId { get; set; }

    [Column( "Deleted", SkipOnUpdate = true ), NotNull]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    [Column( "AccountId" ), NotNull]
    public Guid AccountId { get; set; }

    [Column( "PackageId" ), Nullable]
    public Guid? PackageId { get; set; }

    [Column( "Provider" ), NotNull]
    public string Provider { get; set; }

    [Column( "CustomerId" ), Nullable]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Column( "SubscriptionId" ), Nullable]
    public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }

    [Column( "PaymentMethodToken" ), Nullable]
    public string PaymentMethodToken { get; set; }

    [Column( "Status" ), NotNull]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Column( "CreatedOn" ), NotNull]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [Column( "ValidUntil" ), Nullable]
    public DateTime? ValidUntil { get; set; }

    [Column( "CanceledOn" ), Nullable]
    public DateTime? CanceledOn { get; set; }

    #endregion Members

    #region Associations

    [Association( CanBeNull = true, ThisKey = nameof( AccountId ), OtherKey = nameof( Common.Account.AccountId ) )]
    public Account Account { get; set; }

    [Association( CanBeNull = true, ThisKey = nameof( PackageId ), OtherKey = nameof( Sales.Package.PackageId ) )]
    public Package Package { get; set; }

    #endregion Associations
}
```

Sample query:

```
            query = from q in query
                    join pa in db.ProgramAssigns on new { c = q.ProgramId, s = identityContext.UserId } equals new { c = pa.ProgramId, s = pa.AssigneeId } into paa
                    from pa in paa.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where q.Deleted == false && ( pa != null && pa.Assigner.UserAccount.Account.LatestAccountPayment != null && pa.Assigner.UserAccount.Account.LatestAccountPayment.OrderByDescending(x => x.ValidUntil).FirstOrDefault().ValidUntil > DateTime.Now  )
                    select q;
```

Comment: Please update question with classes and their keys. Also with sample query, will check what happened here.

Comment: Well, current `linq2db` version is 4.4.1. Could you please update to latest version an test again?

Comment: If issue still exists create issue in github repository with all classes, and we can try to reproduce it.